# Should view call the store directly?

Tags: reactjs-flux, flux

From the Flux's TodoMVC example, I saw the TodoApp component is asking the store to get the states.

Should the view create the action and let the dispatcher to call the store instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The views that are listening for the stores' "change" event are called controller-views, because they have this one controller-like aspect: whenever the stores change, they get data from the stores and pass it to their children through props.

The controller-views are the only views that should be calling the stores' getters.  The getters should be the only public API that the stores expose.  Stores have no setters.

It's very tempting to call the stores' getters within the `render()` method of some component deep in the tree, but this is an anti-pattern. It violates the unidirectional data flow, making it more difficult to understand the flow of data through the application, and it and makes your rendering more expensive.

In the TodoMVC Flux example, the TodoApp component is the only controller-view.

Comment: I would take this as answer because I would like to know about how the original idea is.

Answer (score 2):

You should get the values from stores somehow:

1. Get value directly from store. E.g. `postsStore.get('firstPost')`

   You'll not be notified on changes. So, don't use this method.
2. Get & Subscribe to store using lifecycle methods on component

   ```
   componentWillMount: function(){
       var _this = this;
       myStore.subscribe(function(newValue){
           _this.setState({
               myValue: newValue
           });
       })
   },
   componentWillUnmount: function(){
       // don't forget to unsubscribe from store here
   }
   ```
3. Get & Subscribe to store using mixins. Usually Flux implementations gives you Mixin for it. So value from store setting to component state on changes of value in store.

   example from Reflux

   ```
    mixins: Reflux.connect(myStore, 'myValue'),
    render: function(){
        // here you have access to this.state.myValue
    }
   ```
4. Subscribe to action. It can be useful for rendering errors, that you don't want to store. But you can use it for whatever you want.

   Implementation same as previous, but instead `store` use `action`

Best way to sync with stores is to subscribe to store.

---

### So answer to your question is:

**Yes**, it's ok, and **No**, you shouldn't call methods on stores in components.

It's ok to call methods on stores if it's **pure** methods (doesn't change data in store). So you can call only `get` methods.

But if you want (you should) to be **notified on changes** in store, you should subscribe to it. As manual subscribing can be added through mixins, it should use it (your own, or from flux-library). So `SubscribingMixin(MyStore)` calls some methods on store internally, but not you are right in component.

---

But if you think about reinvent Flux, notice, that there is no difference between subscribing to store and subscribing to action. So it's possible to implement it so all data will pass through actions.

Comment: There is a big difference between subscribing to stores and subscribing to actions.  Subscribing to stores is a simple, sane, unidirectional data flow.  Subscribing to actions is a recipe for publish-subscribe spaghetti code.  The dispatcher is your friend here and there are good reasons why it's part of the Flux pattern, as it cleans up a lot of messy code.  The benefit is not obvious in a small app, but as the app grows, the simplicity and cleanliness of the pattern really starts to show itself.

Comment: @fisherwebdev I mean there is no difference programmatically. I don't see any troubles with subscribing to actions. It doesn't blindly follow the FLUX cannons. But if you know what are you doing, sometimes it's definitely better to ignore even most important rules of FLUX. I recommend to read https://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2015/03/20/react-ions-part-2-flux-the-easy-way/ FLUX is just a set of ideas. Great ideas, but if you change something that more fit your needs, it does not necessarily mean bad.

Answer (score 0):

View could get the states of Stores directly.

Action + Dispatcher is the flux way to change the states of the Store, not accessing existing Store data.